# Turpentine - Varnish Cache is giving error connection timeout

Tags: varnish

I am installing varnish extension, when i apply changes/save , it gives following error "Varnnish admin socket timeout". Varnish is working on server.

[image]

here is my default.vcl

```
C{ #include <stdlib.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <time.h> #include <pthread.h> static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; void generate_uuid(char* buf) { pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex); long a = lrand48(); long b = lrand48(); long c = lrand48(); long d = lrand48(); pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex); // SID must match this regex for Kount compat /^\w{1,32}$/ sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx", a, b & 0xffff, (b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000, (c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000, (c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16, d ); return; } }C import std; backend default { .host = "159.253.1.166"; .port = "2222"; .first_byte_timeout = 300s; .between_bytes_timeout = 300s; } backend admin { .host = "159.253.1.166"; .port = "2222"; .first_byte_timeout = 21600s; .between_bytes_timeout = 21600s; } acl crawler_acl { "127.0.0.1"; } acl debug_acl { "62.108.4.250"; } sub generate_session { if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") { set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub( req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1"); } else { C{ char uuid_buf [50]; generate_uuid(uuid_buf); VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ, "\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:", uuid_buf, vrt_magic_string_end ); }C } if (req.http.Cookie) { std.collect(req.http.Cookie); set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session + "; " + req.http.Cookie; } else { set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session; } } sub generate_session_expires { C{ time_t now = time(NULL); struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now); now_tm.tm_sec += 3600; mktime(&now_tm); char date_buf [50]; strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm); VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP, "\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:", date_buf, vrt_magic_string_end ); }C } sub vcl_recv { if (req.restarts == 0) { if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) { set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip; } else { set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip; } } if (!true || req.http.Authorization || req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD)$" || req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") { return (pipe); } set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2"); if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) { if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") { set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip"; } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") { set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate"; } else { unset req.http.Accept-Encoding; } } if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") { set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1"; if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") { set req.backend = admin; return (pipe); } if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") { set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub( req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1"); } if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") { set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub( req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1"); } if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") { set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub( req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1"); set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub( req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1"); if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 && !(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) { error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed"; } } if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=") { if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl || req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") { set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session"; } else { call generate_session; } } if (true && req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") { unset req.http.Cookie; unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session; return (lookup); } if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php)" || req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") { return (pipe); } if (true && req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") { return (pass); } if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") { set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1"); set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1"); } return (lookup); } } sub vcl_pipe { unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake; set bereq.http.Connection = "close"; } sub vcl_hash { hash_data(req.url); if (req.http.Host) { hash_data(req.http.Host); } else { hash_data(server.ip); } hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded); if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) { hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent); } if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) { hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding); } if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) { hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency); } if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" && req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") { hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1")); } return (hash); } sub vcl_hit { } sub vcl_fetch { set req.grace = 15s; set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = req.http.host; set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = req.url; if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") { unset beresp.http.Vary; set beresp.do_gzip = true; if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) { set beresp.ttl = 15s; return (hit_for_pass); } else { if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) { set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie; unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie; } unset beresp.http.Cache-Control; unset beresp.http.Expires; unset beresp.http.Pragma; unset beresp.http.Cache; unset beresp.http.Age; if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") { set beresp.do_esi = true; } if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") { set beresp.ttl = 15s; return (hit_for_pass); } else { if (true && bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") { set beresp.ttl = 28800s; set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800"; } elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) { if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" && req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") { set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"); } if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") { set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub( req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1"); } set beresp.ttl = std.duration( regsub( req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"), 300s); if (beresp.ttl == 0s) { set beresp.ttl = 15s; return (hit_for_pass); } } else { set beresp.ttl = 3600s; } } } return (deliver); } } sub vcl_deliver { if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) { call generate_session_expires; set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session + "; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/"; if (req.http.Host) { set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", ""); } set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly"; unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires; } if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") { set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache"; } if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) { set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits; set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method; set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access; set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency; set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store; } else { unset resp.http.X-Varnish; unset resp.http.Via; unset resp.http.X-Powered-By; unset resp.http.Server; unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache; unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi; unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events; unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block; unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session; unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host; unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL; unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie; } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you follow Nexcess' exact installation guide for their [Turpentine](http://www.nexcess.net/resources/plugins/magento-turpentine-varnish) extension:

[Github | nexcess/magento-turpentine | Installation](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Installation)

Also, Nexcess offer excellent support. Just contact them by opening a ticket (email support@nexcess.net) and they usually respond within minutes.

Alternately, you can call them toll-free:

- **US** +1-866-639-2377
- **UK** +0-808-120-7609
- **AU** 1-800-765-472

Good luck.

Comment: No problem, it'd be helpful to future users if you posted the solution here.